# Upgrading from the June CTP EF 4.2

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

We're currently developing an application that is using EF Code first (EF June 2011 CTP).

My first question is: Is it worth trying to upgrade to use a later version of EF?

Secondly, if so, does anyone know the steps involved to upgrade - when I try to install the NuGet package for EF 5.0 - beta 2, I end up with issues as the target framework is still 4.2.

Many thanks,

James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTP is long time dead with no other version coming because all that stuff is currently part of .NET 4.5 beta and EF 5.0 beta. You must upgrade to those two and the upgrade will consist of re-targeting application back to .NET 4.0 / .NET 4.5, removing all dependencies to your current EF version and re-adding those dependencies for .NET 4.5 / EF 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for the response - the big issue for us here, is that we also have to upgrade to use VS 11 to use EF 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote a blog post on this: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/04/11/entity-framework-zombie-a-k-a-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp/. There is a number of issues with CTP 4.2 because of technical challenges related to shipping a .NET Framework library out of the .NET Framework (like 4.2 target). Move to .NET Framework 4.5 that contains the same feature set as EF 4.2 + bug fixes and has a go-live license. Use EF 5.0 on top of it and you will be in a better world.

Comment: Thanks - interesting blog entry

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.

My main issue is that we rely heavily on ENUMs in our implementation of 4.2 code first.  I attempted to migrate the project to 4.5 but ENUMs are not supported, and there is also an issue with table per hierarchy (which is easy to fix).  The next move will be to upgrade to VS11 and use 5.0 - but this is a big undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

@jwsadler:
Enums are supported by core EF libraries released as part of .net Framework 4.5 (e.g. System.Data.Entity.dll). To make enums work with CodeFirst/DbContext you do need EF 5.0.0 package from NuGet (use `Install-Package EntityFramework -pre` (-pre is important)). You need VS 11 for this since Visual Studio 2010 cannot be used to create applications that target .NET Framework 4.5. Note that when installing the nuget package on Visual Studio 11 the target version of the .NET Framework set for the project is taken into account. If you target .NET Framework 4 you will not be able to use EF5 features like enums or spatial.